# A string blowup method

Tags: java, string

I am trying to make a method that returns a version of the original string as follows: each digit 0-9 that appears in the original string is replaced by that many occurrences of the character to the right of the digit. So the string "a3tx2z" yields "attttxzzz", and "12x" yields "2xxx". A digit not followed by a character (i.e. at the end of the string) is replaced by nothing.

I've written the code but it only works for just the first digit and remains unchanged for the next ones.

```
public String blowUp( String str ){

        StringBuffer buffer = null;
        String toAdd = null;
        String toReturnString = null;

        if( str.length() == 0 ){

            return "no string found";
        }else{

            for( int count = 0; count < str.length(); count++ ){

                char c = str.charAt( count );

                if( count == str.length() - 1 ){

                    if( Character.isDigit( c ) ){

                        return str.substring( 0, count );
                    }else{

                        return str;
                    }
                }else if( Character.isDigit( c ) ){

                    char next = str.charAt( count + 1 );
                    buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    int nooftimes = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString( c ));

                    for( int j = 0; j < nooftimes; j++ ){

                        buffer.append( next );
                    }
                    toAdd = buffer.toString();
                    toReturnString = str.substring( 0, count ) + toAdd + str.substring( count + 1 );
                    return toReturnString;
                }
            }
        return toReturnString;
        }
    //  return toReturnString;
    }
```

Comment: You're returning right away if the first character is a digit...and at the end of the loop, you return the unchanged string!

Answer (score 1):

See the comments.

```
public String blowUp(String str) {

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        // String toAdd = null;
        // String toReturnString = null;

        if (str.length() == 0) {
            return "no string found";
        } else {

            for (int count = 0; count < str.length(); count++) {

                char c = str.charAt(count);
                /*
                 * if (count == str.length() - 1) {
                 * 
                 * if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                 * 
                 * return str.substring(0, count); } else {
                 * 
                 * return str; } } else
                 */
                if (Character.isDigit(c) && count < str.length()-1) {

                    char next = str.charAt(count + 1);

                    if (!Character.isDigit(next)) { // append only if next
                                                    // character isn't digit

                        // buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        int nooftimes = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c));

                        for (int j = 0; j < nooftimes; j++) {

                            buffer.append(next);
                        }

                    } else {
                        buffer.append(str.charAt(count+1)); // append digit followed by another digit with next digit
                    }
                    // toAdd = buffer.toString();
                    // toReturnString = str.substring(0, count) + toAdd
                    // + str.substring(count + 1);
                } else {
                    buffer.append(c); // simply append if not digit
                }
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }
        // return toReturnString;
    }
```

Comment: Nit Pick: What happens if the `String` ends with a digit?

Comment: Better, but you're appending the last character (in this case a digit) to the end of the result, which is, as I read the requirements, not what is expected.  The rest of the answer is right on the ball and I'm just being an old farty-pants ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think it is what OP wanted. **A digit not followed by a character (i.e. at the end of the string) is replaced by nothing.** Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Okay.  If I input `a3tx2z`, I get `attttxzzz`, but it should be `atttxzz`.  If I input `a3tx2z1`, I get `attttxzzz1` when, as I understand the requirements, it should be `atttxzz` - I might be wrong on that point ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Edited again :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer, if you input `a3tx2z`, it should be `attttxzzz` as OP said.

Comment: Really, cause as I read the specs it should take "`t` and repeat it 3 times" - *"each digit 0-9 that appears in the original string is replaced by that many occurrences of the character to the right of the digit"* - Either the spec is wrong or the examples.  In that case, we're all right :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer _So the string "a3tx2z" yields "attttxzzz", and "12x" yields "2xxx"._ Anyway, I'm out of here. OP is silent, no respones.

Comment: Lol - I'd give you another +1 for the effort if I could.  See, this is why it's important to get good specs ;)

Comment: @Mad: Judging by the example output, I think the spec is simply missing the phrase "all non-digits in the input are output as-is". That's why `a3tx2z` results in `attttxzzz`: `a` is output as-is, `3` is replaced with `ttt`, `t` is output as-is, etc.

Comment: the question is apparently correct. a t(from the question) followed by 3 more t's  and likewise for a x followed by 2 more x's as the task wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making this more complicated than it has to be, and in the process getting the logic a bit confused.

In pseudocode, this problem basically boils down to the following:

```
for every character 'c' in the input, starting from the first:
    if c is not a digit:
        add c to the output
    otherwise (i.e. if c is a digit), if c is not the last character in the input:
        let 'x' be the number represented by c
        let 'n' be the next character in the input after c
        add x copies of n to the output
return the output
```

I'll leave translating that into Java to you<sup>*</sup>.

---

*    **EDIT:** or to [@TheKojuEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150335/214149)!

Answer (score 0):

There are no less than 5 `return` points in your code, this is really, really bad.  It makes it impossible to accurately determine what is going on in your code.

I'm old school, so I believe in one entry point and one exit point for any method, it makes it SO much easier to figure out what's going on...

Let's start with...

```
    if( str.length() == 0 ){
        return "no string found";
```

This should actually be returning the original `String` unchanged...don't you think...

```
            if( count == str.length() - 1 ){
                if( Character.isDigit( c ) ){
                    return str.substring( 0, count );
                }else{
                    return str;
                }
```

I can't even figure out why you would need this.  The last character is no more special than the first, apart from the fact that if it's a digit, you should ignore it...

```
                char next = str.charAt( count + 1 );
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int nooftimes = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString( c ));
                for( int j = 0; j < nooftimes; j++ ){
                    buffer.append( next );
                }
                toAdd = buffer.toString();
                toReturnString = str.substring( 0, count ) + toAdd + str.substring( count + 1 );
                return toReturnString;
```

Then your `return` here!  But you've only entered this section of code once!  What about the rest of the `String`?

You also seem to be ignoring all the other characters in the `String` from what I can tell...

A simpler idea would be to use the `StringBuffer` (or `StringBuilder` as I prefer) and keep appending the resulting values to it, for example...

```
public static String blowUp(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
    for (int count = 0; count < str.length(); count++) {
        char c = str.charAt(count);
        if (Character.isDigit(c) && count < str.length() - 1) {
            char next = str.charAt(count + 1);
            int nooftimes = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c));
            for (int j = 0; j < nooftimes; j++) {
                sb.append(next);
            }
            count++;
        } else if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Example input output**

If I input...

```
a3tx2z    
12x    
a3tx2z1    
12x1
```

I get

```
atttxzz
2x
atttxzz
2x
```

as output

Answer (score 0):

@MadProgrammer I modified a little bit based on your code.

```
public String blowup(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i =0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(c) && i < str.length()-1) {
            char next = str.charAt(i+1);
            if(!Character.isDigit(next)) {
                int repTimes = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c));
                for(int k = 0; k < repTimes; k++) {
                    sb.append(next);
                }
            }
            else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
        else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return new String(sb);
}
```